# How to Flag Accessibility Insights Results as Ignored or Won't Fix?

Tags: accessibility-insights

Is there a way using the *Accessibility Insights for Web* browser extension to flag certain results as ones that are "known" but will not or cannot be fixed so that they stop showing up in assessment reports?

I'd like to have the development team run the Fast Pass assessment as part of their PR submission/review but there are a few items which will fail consistently and we cannot fix them (at least right now) so I'd like to avoid having them as false-positives in the results but be able to find them again when we can address the underlying problem.

I'm thinking something like `es-lint-ignore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teams using Accessibility Insights for Web can't currently mark certain elements/rules as out of scope for FastPass, but we do have [an open feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/issues/1942) for being able to target/exclude certain elements in the DOM; I recommend leaving a comment/upvoting to indicate community interest in us exploring this in the future!

Comment: Thanks, @Jacqueline Gibson!  The issue linked to wasn't quite what I was looking for so I created a new one: https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/issues/6639